# Failing to see anything on localhost using typescript for Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Here is my code below:
Note: I am still learning typescript and the rest of the stuff so let me know for other stuff that I should do better!

Folder structure:
[image: folder]

server.ts

```
import http, { createServer, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } 
from "http";
import * as app from "./app";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const server = createServer(app);

server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

app.ts

```
import express, { Application } from "express";

const app: Application = express();
const mealsRoutes = require("./routes/meals");

app.use("/meals", mealsRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

meals.ts

```
import express, { Request, Response} from "express";

const router= express.Router();
//GET ROUTE for /meals/
router.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        message:"Handling GET request to /meals"
    });
});
//POST ROUTE for /meals/
router.post("/", (req: Request, res: Response, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        message:"Handling POST request to /meals"
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "restful-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node dist/server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

package-lock.json: https://codeshare.io/Pd4ExY (had to share with this)

So when I run it with "node dist/server.js" and test it on the browser nothing happens, no errors, it just keeps loading. I have no clue what am I doing wrong, any help?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, questions are expected to be ***self-contained***; that is, containing all relevant code, error messages, and other pertinent debugging information **as text, in the body of your question**, with code snippets conforming to the guidance on creating a [mre]. Sharing information in screenshots/images unnecessarily reduces accessibility and searchability by future visitors to this question (and is arguably more time-consuming to take a screenshot of said code/errors rather than simply creating a [mre] and pasting it here). [ask]

Comment: How are you compiling your ts to js?

Comment: I have watcher turned on with: "tsc -w"

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshots. Use the code button (icon looks like `{}`) in the editor to format code.

Comment: Can you please provide code so we can reproduce the application on our local machines?

Comment: Just edited, sorry :/

Comment: Thanks! Can you please provide your package.json and package-lock.json code too so we don't have to install the dependencies ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the port actually is loaded correctly. If `process.env.PORT` ends up being `undefined` you get a random port. You can either add a debugger or e.g. print the port when the server has started:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.addListener('listening', () => console.log(server.address().port));
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

The rest of the code looks fine if you are accessing the path `/meals`.

Comment: Tried adding the extra line but it says: "Object is possibly 'null'" and "Property port does not exist on type string". I even tried putting instead of process.env.PORT value 3000, but still nothing :/

Comment: That was just some quick JS code, you can ignore the errors for purposes of testing, e.g. by inserting `// @ts-ignore` on the line before the error. So you tried port `3000` and then the URL `http://localhost:3000/meals`?

Comment: It just keeps loading, but I can see this message in console: `crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.   VM526:7374 `

Comment: @brmbi I cannot tell what else could be wrong then. If you want i can delete this answer, as it did nothing.